# How do I select which editText is used first?

Tags: android, cursor, android-edittext, selected

I have two edit text fields on my phone:

'Name:' and 'Phone:'

Whenever I launch my program, my cursor is already in the 'phone' field with the number keyboard pulled up.  However, I'd like for it to center on the first editText, 'name', so that the regular keyboard pulls up.

Does anybody know why this is working this way, and how to correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(EditText)txtName = findViewById(R.id.NAME_ID);
txtName.requestFocus();
```

Do this in your onCreate() after you've inflated your layout

Answer (score 0):

See `requestFocus` tag on your layout

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in code with a requestFocus() method on the view:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus()

or with an  tag inside the view tag in the layout:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html#requestfocus-element